# Unable to open *.java files in eclipse after installing PyDev

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I installed PyDev in eclipse to add support for python,

it's was going great until I found out I cannot open *.java files anymore, but when I uninstall PyDev, I can open *.java files.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: What happens? What does the right click "Open With..." menu show?

Comment: It's set to java editor. Also right click menu and clicking "Open" works

Comment: What happens instead of opening? Does anything get added to the Error Log?

Comment: Nope, Nothing added to error log, Just does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was some regression en Eclipse itself (as nothing changed in the area in PyDev in many years but Eclipse `2022-03` started misbehaving when the `PyDev Navigator Content` is enabled in the `Project Explorer` -- or maybe they fixed some bug that PyDev relied on    ).

I still need to investigate if this is fixable in the PyDev side...

Right now the workarounds available are:

1. Don't use the `Project Explorer` (i.e.: keep to the `Package Explorer` or `PyDev Package Explorer`).
2. Disable `PyDev Navigator Content` in the `Project Explorer` (see image below).

[image: Disable PyDev Navigator Content in the Project Explorer]

Comment: As a note, I've just fixed this in https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/commit/86dc8967daa3ca1dcd5c5585a0398dde3f9c8d36 (so, a fix will be available in the next release -- probably in something as `PyDev 10.0.1`).

Comment: Where can I get PyDev 10.0.1?

Comment: When the next release is done (it's still not released).